# Python. TweepError: [{'code': 34, 'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist.'}]

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, twitter, tweepy

I want to run this code

def get_all_tweets(screen_name):

```
#initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
alltweets = []
#make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum   allowed count)
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)
#save most recent tweets
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
#save the id of the oldest tweet less one
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

while len(new_tweets) > 0:  
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
    # print(alltweets[-1]['id'])
    #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
```

TweepError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
221     for x in usernames:
222         print(x)
--> 223         user_info=get_all_tweets(x)

```
224         all_fet.append(compute_features(x,user_info))
225     #
```

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py in execute(self)
232                     raise RateLimitError(error_msg, resp)
233                 else:
--> 234                     raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
235
236             # Parse the response payload

TweepError: [{'code': 34, 'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist.'}]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using V4.x of `Tweepy` instead of V3.x.

It makes more detail option and flexible.

Using `get_users_tweets()` can get user's tweets.

Documentation in [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#manage-tweets)
[image]

```py
import tweepy

def get_all_tweets(user_name):
    bearer_token ="<your access token>"
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

    user = client.get_user(username=user_name)
    user_id = user.data.id

    count = 0
    next_token = 1
    limit = 1000
    userTweets = []
    while next_token != None and count < limit:
        tweets = client.get_users_tweets(id=user_id, max_results=100)
        if tweets.data is not None:
            for tweet in tweets.data:
                count += 1
                userTweets.append({
                    "id": tweet.id,
                    "test": tweet.text
                })
            if (tweets.meta['next_token']) is not None:
                next_token = tweets.meta['next_token']
            else:
                next_token = None
        else:
            next_token = None
    return userTweets

userTweets = get_all_tweets('elonmusk')
for tweet in userTweets:
    print(tweet)

print(len(userTweets))
```

Result
[image]

Berer Token get by Token API or Copy from your Developer Dashboard

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials
```

```
Username <- API KEY
Password <- API Secret
```

[image]

```
https://developer.twitter.com/
```

[image]